# Find files with padded with zeros after fsarchiver backup

Tags: bash, filesystems

My SSD was dying so I tried to backup my /home with [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Main_Page) but during the process I got a bunch of errors like : `file has been truncated: padding with zeros.`

Now I'm trying to locate those files so Im' searching for a bash/python/perl... script allowing me to search for non-empty files with the last n bytes 'padded with zeros'.

Thank you in advance for your help and please excuse my english.

Comment: if you have a file you are sure that was truncated, use `od -c filename` and paste in the last few lines of output here using the `{}` tool after clicking on the `edit` link above. Right now, we can't be sure if padded with zeros means zero-valued bytes, or the ascii '0' char. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script takes a list of files on the command line and reports the names of those whose last ten bytes padded with zeros:

```
#!/bin/sh
for fname in "$@"
do
    if [ -s "$fname" -a "$(tail -c10 "$fname"  | tr -d '\000' | wc -c)" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo Truncated file: $fname
    fi
done
```

It works by first checking that the file is non-empty (`[ -s "$fname" ]`) and then it takes the last ten bytes of the file (`tail -c10 "$fname"`) and removes any bytes (`tr -d '\000'`) and then counts how many bytes are left (`wc -c`).  If all of the last ten bytes are zeros, then there will be no bytes left, and the file is reported as truncated.

If you want to use something other than 10 bytes in your test,  adjust the `tail` option to suit.

If you test all the files in some directory or filesystem, `find` can assist.  If the above script is in an executable file name padded.sh, then run:

```
find path/to/suspect/files -size +10c -exec padded.sh {} +
```